# SQLAlchemy filter query again

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, subquery

I want to count a users amount of buildings in each category.

I have a query very much like this:

```
q = session.query(buildings, category_buildings)\
           .join(category_buildings, category_buildings.id == buildings.category)\
           .filter(buildings.builder_id == user_id)

for cid in range(1, category_count):
    q.filter(category_buildings.id == cid)
    buildings_for_cid = q.all()
```

The q.filter() inside the for loop doesn't give me the desired result, as it doesnt filter by category id at all. What do I do?

In plain SQL: (the AND C.id = INT would happen in the for loop)

```
SELECT * FROM buildings B
JOIN category_buildings C ON B.category = C.id
WHERE builder_id = 1
AND C.id = 1
```

Comment: Try like this : `session.query(buildings).join(category_buildings)
           .filter(buildings.builder_id == user_id)`

Comment: I simplified the join for the sake of this question. The joins are actually a little more complex because the db model uses mapping tables, but they work already, I am getting all desired columns.

Comment: [`Query`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query) objects are generative; most operations, such as `filter()`, return a *new `Query` object*. In other words assign the result of `q.filter(category_buildings.id == cid)` to something and use that. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021899/what-is-a-generative-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `q.all()` you were essentially just running the first-line query, with `.all()` on the end, because the second filter you applied wasn't stored as q.

So essentially you did this:

```
q = 'abc'
for cid in range(1, 10):
   q.upper()
   print(q)
```

You're expecting `q` to be `'ABC'` but it never actually gets modified.  What I think you actually want to do is:

```
q = session.query(buildings, category_buildings) \
    .join(category_buildings, category_buildings.id == buildings.category) \
    .filter(buildings.builder_id == user_id)

for cid in range(1, category_count):
    branched = q.filter(category_buildings.id == cid)
    buildings_for_cid = branched.all()
```